# why /usr/lib/ld connot find -lcudadevrt?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm learning the cuda programming
when compiling the example code from <>

```
nvcc -o hello hello.cu
```

it returns

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudadevt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart_static
```

but my cuda config appears well,
my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH` already include the right path of cuda.

How to do it?

Comment: where does LD_LIBRARY_PATH point to? which files are there? it should point to the .so files

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a run time link loader setting. It has nothing to do with linkage behaviour. Nvcc should be able to find those libraries without any user intervention. If it can't, you likely have a broken toolkit installation

Comment: `cuda` is (or was, I haven't looked in a long time) completely C++.  Nvidia is lying (or "marketing", not really sure what the difference is) when they refer to "Cuda C".  You should remove the C tag.

Comment: @ShlomiAgiv thank you, LD_LIBRARY_PATH  points to /usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64 as the installation instruction decleared.

Comment: @talonmies thanks, maybe I'll check for it twice.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks. Not very sure about what you are talking about \cry , but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH are runtime variables. At link time you must specify the location of the shared object using the linker's `-L` flag.

Comment: thank you！I remember I did explicitly link it. My command is   nvcc -o hello hello.cu -L/usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64 I'll check it again!